# How to get a name of constructor from an instance in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, class, typescript

I have a basic class:

```
export default class UserHomeHandler {
    public init() {
        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
}
```

Compiler complains with this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'.
```

How do I get 'UserHomeHandler' as string from an instance of this class?

Comment: `(<any> this.constructor).name` or maybe the `.d.ts` files have to be updated if `name` is present consistently on functions

Comment: Thanks @bali182, it helped. Can it be done more elegantly though without having to casting to any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an external `.d.ts` file and augment the `Function` type in it (idea extracted from danquirk's answer on this github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2076):

**function-name.d.ts**

```
interface Function {
  name: string
}
```

Then import that definition:

```
/// <reference path='function-name.d.ts'/>

export default class UserHomeHandler {
  public init() {
    // should compile
    console.log(this.constructor.name);
  } 
}
```

Far from elegant, I know. If you don't like this approach, you can always cast to `any`.